# Using Eloquent relationship to retrieve data for child relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and MySQL. I have `categories`, `sub_categories`, `category_info`, and `services`.

A `category` can have 1 or more `sub_categories`. A `category` belongs to one menu category

A `sub_category` has only one `category`.

A `category` has 1 `category` info record. It doesn't matter if its a `category` or `sub_category` it will have one record in the category_info table.

My table structure is as follows

Menu_Categories

```
id
1,
2
```

Categories

```
id, parent_category_id, menu_category_id 
1, null, 1
2, null, 1
3, 1, null
4, 1, null
```

Category_Info

```
category_id, name 
1, Legal Services 
2, Misc 
3, US Legal Services 
4, Europe Legal Services
```

Controller

```php
$cats = MenuCategories
        ::with(['categories', 'categories.info', 'categories.sub_categories'])
        ->get();
```

Menu Categories Model

```php
public function categories() {
    return $this->hasMany(Categories::class, 'menu_category_id', 'id');
}
```

Categories Model

```php
public function menu_categories() {
    return $this->belongsTo(MenuCategories::class, 'menu_category_id');
}

   public function sub_categories() {
    return $this->hasOne(Categories::class, 'parent_category_id');
}

public function info() {
    return $this->hasOne(CategoryInfo::class, 'category_id');
}
```

SubCategory Info Model

```php
    public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(CategoryInfo::class);
}
```

I need to return the categories and the category info as follows

```php
{
    Categories: {
        {
            id: 1,
            parent_category_id, null,
            Sub_Categories: {
                {
                    id: 3
                    parent_category_id: 1
                    Category_Info: {
                        {
                            category_id: 3,
                            name: US Legal Services
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: 4
                    parent_category_id: 1,
                    Category_Info: {
                        {
                            category_id: 4,
                            name: Europe Legal Services
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            Category_Info: {
                {
                    category_id: 3,
                    name: Legal Services
                }
            }
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            parent_category_id, null,
            Category_Info: {
                {
                    category_id: 3,
                    name: Misc
                }
            }
        },
    }
}
```

With the way I have relationships set up it is returning data incorrectly. It is not returning Category_Info for `sub_categories`.

```php
{
    Categories: {
        {
            id: 1,
            parent_category_id, null,
            Sub_Categories: {
                {
                    id: 3
                    parent_category_id: 1
                },
                {
                    id: 4
                    parent_category_id: 1,
                },
            },
            Category_Info: {
                {
                    category_id: 3,
                    name: Legal Services
                }
            }
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            parent_category_id, null,
            Category_Info: {
                {
                    category_id: 3,
                    name: Misc
                }
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Is it possible to return Category_Info for the `sub_categories` as well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'categories.sub_categories.info'`?

Comment: it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Jonas Staudenmeir for helping me out

`$cats = MenuCategories
        ::with(['categories', 'categories.info', 'categories.sub_categories', 'categories.sub_categories.info'])
        ->get();`